# Creating a Junit test that tests conection to SQL Server

Tags: sql, spring, unit-testing, junit, integration-testing

I am having a great deal of difficulty in either understanding what I am doing wrong or missing something fundamental. I have searched for my problem for a day or so and not understanding what I am missing.

So what I am trying to do is Create a JUnit test that connects to my SQL server and does a query to get the current time. My connection to the server works and I have tested my SQL code in the Query on the server and works perfectly. For some reason the test isn't sending my code and getting anything returned.. Not sure what Ive done wrong an if this is too extensive for this form(little new to this)

```java
@Override
    public Timestamp PCNow() throws PCSQLException {

        //SQL Server uses GETDATAE
        String strSQL = "SELECT GETDATE()";;

        try {
            //Get a result set with the timestamp field
            Timestamp datTs = (Timestamp)jdbcTemplate.queryForObject( strSQL, Timestamp.class );

            //Make sure there is a result
            if ( datTs == null )
                //Throw an exception indicating the server could not give a time
                throw new PCSQLException( "UNABLE_SERVER_TIME" );

            return datTs;
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            throw new PCSQLException( "This didn't work PCNow", e );
        }
    }
```

This is my Test class

```java
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations = {"classpath:applicationContext-sql.xml"} )
//instantiate TestExecutionListener class 
@TestExecutionListeners

public class ConnectionAdapterSQLTest {

  @Autowired
    ConnectionAdapterImpl connectionAdapterPC;

    private final Log log = LogFactory.getLog( getClass() );

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {

    }

    /**
     * @throws java.lang.Exception
     */
    @After
    public void tearDown() throws Exception {
    }


    @Test
    public final void testPCNow()  {
        log.info("testPCNow()");

        //fail("Not yet implemented");
    }
```

applicationContext-sql.xml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd">

    <!-- connection to Sql Server using JDBC sqljdbc4.2 -->
    <bean id="dataSourcePC" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver" />
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:sqlserver://******;databaseName=******" /> 
        <property name="username" value="******" />
        <property name="password" value="******" /> 
    </bean>

    <bean id="connectionAdapterPC"
        class="com.*******.*******.connections.ConnectionAdapterSQL">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSourcePC" />
        <property name="useConnectionPool" value="false" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="dxDateTimeFormatter" class="com.*******.*******.data.format.DateTimeFormatter">
        <property name="dateFormat" value="dd-MMM-yyyy" />
    </bean>

</beans>
```

Comment: Can you add your `applicationContext-sql.xml` to the question?

Answer (score 0):

Matt, you are logging the String "testPCNow()" not invoking the method PCNow().

So replace the test method:

```
@Test
public void testPCNow() {
    log.info(new TheClassThatContainsTestPCNowMethod().PCNow());
}
```

Remember replacing TheClassThatContainsTestPCNowMethod with a valid constructor of the class that contains the method PCNow().

Comment: Wouldn't I also need dependencies and others in order for the class to run? Maybe I am just not understanding how Junit testing works in Spring. I also tried that and got a null pointer

Comment: Hi Matt, could you please post the stacktrace with the NullPointerException?

Comment: I think the problem is that My connection to my SQL server isn't working I've aded this a system out to see if the connection is working and its returning true so I think that is why my class isn't working properly. Unless you can help me with that otherwise? but all in all thank you for your help @Before
 public void setUp() throws Exception {
  System.out.println(connectionAdapterPC == null);
  System.out.println(dataSourcePC == null);
 }